# How to bypass ID column without being used in the training model but have it as output - Azure ML

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

The input data in the model includes column ControlNo.

[image]

But I don't want this column being part of learning process so I'm using `Select Columns in Dataset` to exclude `ControlNo` column.

But as a output I want those columns:

```
ControlNo, Score Label, Score Probability
```

So basically I need NOT to include column `ControlNo` into learning process,
but have it as output along with `Score Label` column.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Hey Oleg, can you confirm if my answer helped (or not :) ), so that other visitors can get an idea of how to fix this issue for themselves?

Comment: Sorry Vlad. Finally got time to get to it. Your answer definitely helped. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of removing the ControlNo column from the dataset, you can use the [Edit Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/edit-metadata) module to clear its "Feature" flag - just select the column and set **Fields** to **Clear feature**.

[image: Edit Metadata settings]

This will cause the Azure ML Studio algorithms to ignore it during training, and you'll be able to return it as part of your output.